# How to list out post category name and description in page

Tags: categories

I want to display this all categories and description in home page and for each category the division will be like this:

Category name
        
        
        
          
             **Category Description**
          
        
        
        Link to particular Categories post.

Help me that how  to list out my categories name & in description how to add the  tag in wordpress?

Comment: What have you tried so far, what code have you written so far, where are you going wrong, what error does your code give you. Please edit your question and add all relevant code, effort and research. As your question currently stands, it is a do-my-work-for-me type of question, which WPSE is not

Answer (score 0):

Use [`wp_list_categories`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories)

Here's all the parameters

```
<?php $args = array(
'show_option_all'    => '',
'orderby'            => 'name',
'order'              => 'ASC',
'style'              => 'list',
'show_count'         => 0,
'hide_empty'         => 1,
'use_desc_for_title' => 1,
'child_of'           => 0,
'feed'               => '',
'feed_type'          => '',
'feed_image'         => '',
'exclude'            => '',
'exclude_tree'       => '',
'include'            => '',
'hierarchical'       => 1,
'title_li'           => __( 'Categories' ),
'show_option_none'   => __( 'No categories' ),
'number'             => null,
'echo'               => 1,
'depth'              => 0,
'current_category'   => 0,
'pad_counts'         => 0,
'taxonomy'           => 'category',
'walker'             => null
); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you. but do you know about the how to add the html tag in category description field??